# Manipulating List<String> using Linq in C#

Tags: c#, linq

i've  a List< String> like

```
   List<String> ListOne = new List<string> { "A-B", "B-C" };
```

i need to split each string if it contains '-' and add to the same list

So the result will be like

```
 { "A-B", "B-C","A","B","C" };
```

Now i'm using like

```
       for (int i = 0; i < ListOne.Count; i++)
        {
            if (ListOne[i].Contains('-'))
            {
               List<String> Temp = ListOne[i].Split('-').ToList();
               ListOne= ListOne.Union(Temp).ToList();
            }
        }
```

is there any way to do this using LINQ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ListOne.Union(ListOne.SelectMany(i => i.Split('-')))
```

Comment: This won't add it to the same list, it will create a new `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: @JaredPar if thats what he is looking for, yours is likely more efficient, but it's too late where I am to run tests.

Comment: not worried at all about efficiency.  Just noting the slight difference in what the OP was asking for.  Yours could be easily modified to meet it.

Comment: @JaredPar I meant if he did `ListOne = new List(myExpression);`

Answer (score 3):

Try the following

```
List.AddRange(
  ListOne
    .Where(x => x.Contains("-"))
    .SelectMany(x => x.Split('-'))
    .Distinct()
    .ToList());
```